# Fastify & socket.io server client doesn't connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, fastify, socket.io-client

How can we connect fastify backend server with socket.io ? Can anyone suggest me what I did wrong in following code?

Error Code:-

```
"res": {"statusCode": 404}
```

```
index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Look at the server log to see if the connection happened</h1>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-c79GN5VsunZvi+Q/WObgk2in0CbZsHnjEqvFxC5DxHn9lTfNce2WW6h2pH6u/kF+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    const socket = io();
  </script>
</html>
```

```
Server.js


const fastify = require('fastify')
const socketio = require('fastify-socket.io')
const { join } = require('path')
const { readFile } = require('fs').promises

const app = fastify({ logger: true })

app.register(socketio)

app.get('/', async (req, reply) => {
  const data = await readFile(join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
  reply.header('content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
  reply.send(data)
})

app.ready(err => {
  if (err) throw err

  app.io.on('connect', (socket) => console.info('Socket connected!', socket.id))
})

app.listen({ port: 3000 })
```

dependencies:
"fastify": "^4.22.2", "fastify-socket.io": "^4.0.0", "path": "^0.12.7", "socket.io": "^4.7.2"

Tried Connecting server with client but unable to do it. Please suggest a way to connect fastify with socket.io

Comment: can you share your directory structure? a `404` error may indicate that the `index.html` is not detected.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [npm `fastify-socket.io` page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-socket.io/v/4.0.0) it says:

> Supports Fastify versions 3.x

So it does not work for this reason mainly.

Socket.io is not standard, and it does not create a socket: https://socket.io/docs/v3/how-it-works/
It implements a custom handshake pattern and the first contact is an `HTTP GET /socket.io/` request. You are getting 404 for this reason:

[image: 404]

The route is missing from the fastify server.

So, you have these options:

- Switch to fastify 3 (that is out of support)
- Implement the socket.io handshake into fastify: https://socket.io/docs/v3/how-it-works/
- Use standard web socket

For the last one, it is very simple: install the officially supported [`@fastify/websocket`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fastify/websocket) module that supports a lot of feature such as routing and connection helpers.

```js
const app = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
const { readFile } = require('fs').promises
const { join } = require('path')

app.register(require('@fastify/websocket'))
  .after(() => {

    app.get('/', {
      handler: async (req, reply) => {
        const data = await readFile(join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
        reply.header('content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        reply.send(data)
      },
      wsHandler: (connection /* SocketStream */, req /* FastifyRequest */) => {
        connection.socket.on('message', message => {
          // message.toString() === 'hi from client'
          connection.socket.send('hi from server')
        })
      }
    })
  })


app.listen({ host: '0.0.0.0', port: 3000 })
```

and:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Look at the server log to see if the connection happened</h1>
</body>

<script>
  // open a web socket:
  var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

  socket.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
    console.log("Connected to server");
    socket.send("Hello Server!");
  });

  // listen for messages:
  socket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    console.log("Message from server ", event.data);
  });
</script>

</html>
```