# Why socket.io does not work with fastify?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, fastify

When I try to connect from a client to `socket.io` I get the following error:

> polling.js:321  GET http://localhost:4999/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OheO-bi 404 (Not Found)

Here's my code:

```
import fastify from "fastify";
import { Server as ioServer } from "socket.io";

const fastify = fastify();
const io = new ioServer(fastify.server);

fastifyStatic(fastify, { root: __dirтame + path.join("/static") });

fastify.register(fastifyMultipart, {
    attachFieldsToBody: true,
    limits: {
        fieldNameSize: 36,
        fieldSize: 100,
        fields: 10,
        fileSize: config.maxFileAttachmentSizeInBytes,
        files: 1,
        headerPairs: 2000,
    }
});

function MainPage(req, res) => {
    res.type("text/html; charset=utf-8");
    res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
            <script defer src="/assets/client/vendor-react.bundle.js"></script><script defer src="/assets/client/index.bundle.js"></script>
        </head> 
        <body> 
        <div id="root"></div> 
        </body> 
    </html>`.trim().toString());
}

fastify.get("/", (req, res) => {
    MainPage(req, res);
});
fastify.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    MainPage(req, res);
});

fastify.listen({ 4999 }, (err, address) => {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log(address);
});


io.sockets.on("connection", async function (socket) {
    socket.on("error", console.error);

    socket.on("getMessages", async (callback) => {
        const messages = await getMessages();
        callback(messages);
    });

    socket.emit("messages", await getMessages());
});
```

I tried to connect the `fastify-socket.io` module, but it didn't help me. The client part is written in recata and I connect `socket.io` like this:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const URL = isProduction ? undefined : "http://localhost:4999";

export const socket = io(URL, {
    autoConnect: true
});
```

I also tried adding these settings when creating socket.io, but that didn’t help either

```
io = new ioServer(this.fastify.server, {
    cors: {
        origin: `http://localhost:4999`,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastify & socket.io server client doesn't connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77049816/fastify-socket-io-server-client-doesnt-connect)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help me

Comment: It is the same 404 error - what did you tried?